# Using cl-glfw3 on windows

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, glfw, sbcl, cffi

I'm trying to load the library cl-glfw3 with sbcl amd64 for windows. But all I've got is a message with a missing dll. The libffi-6.dll and glfw3.dll are on the same folder that the lisp program.

```
* (ql:quickload "cl-glfw3")

To load "cl-glfw3":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-glfw3
; Loading "cl-glfw3"
...........
debugger invoked on a LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10030E7443}>:
  Unable to load any of the alternatives:
   ("libffi-6.dll" "libffi-5.dll" "libffi.dll")

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY                        ] Try loading the foreign library again.
  1: [USE-VALUE                    ] Use another library instead.
  2: [TRY-RECOMPILING              ] Recompile init and try loading it again
  3: [RETRY                        ] Retry
                                     loading FASL for #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-libffi" "libffi" "init">.
  4: [ACCEPT                       ] Continue, treating
                                     loading FASL for #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cffi-libffi" "libffi" "init">
                                     as having been successful.
  5:                                 Retry ASDF operation.
  6: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the
                                     configuration.
  7: [ABORT                        ] Give up on "cl-glfw3"
  8:                                 Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(FL-ERROR "Unable to load any of the alternatives:~%   ~S" ("libffi-6.dll" "libffi-5.dll" "libffi.dll"))
```

Copying the files to the windows folder no works.

On linux it works ok.

Comment: This is how `CFFI` searches for foreign linraries: https://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/load_002dforeign_002dlibrary.html

Comment: "The libffi-6.dll and glfw3.dll are on the same folder that the lisp program"  That might not be where it's looking for them.  Vsevolod Dyomkin's comment looks useful in that regard.

Comment: If you want a quick hack to see if it will work stick the dlls in the same directory as the lisp .exe file. Then read the link above and find the proper place for then to go :)

Comment: I tried to copy the dlls to the windows folder, sbcl folder and project folder. Nothings works.